# Can GoClipse v0.91 open definition?

Tags: go, goclipse

I have installed golang1.4 and GoClipse v0.91, but I want to open `fmt.Printf()` definition,it displays "Cannot run program oracle". I google this and know that oracle is a plugin for GoClipse, but I cannot find the gooracle.exe or something other like this.And I try to download `gooracle`, but find nothing. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

do `go get golang.org/x/tools/oracle`, `oracle` will be placed in `$GOPATH/bin/`, then you need to config its path in `Eclipse Preference -> Go -> Tool -> Go oracle path`

Comment: I think you may have to explicitly follow up with go build golang.org/x/tools/oracle to get it to show up.

Also, I found that you will have to explicitly set GOOS, GOARCH and provide a wrapper script on Mac OS X 10.9, since /usr/local/go/bin isn't on the Eclipse path by default.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse open **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **Go** -> **Tools** and
Click the **button** `Download Go oracle`